# API information to separate variables

Tags: php, arrays

I'm using an API my teacher made and so far I'm able to get some information out of it.
But I need to get certain information into variables, so I can push it to my database. I decodes the information so far, and it looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [homeClub] => Roda JC
            [awayClub] => Feyenoord
        )
[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [homeClub] => SC Cambuur
        [awayClub] => Feyenoord
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [homeClub] => Heracles Almelo
        [awayClub] => Feyenoord
    )
And so on
```

But now I need to get both `homeClub` and `awayClub` each in a separate variable, and I'm stuck.
If anyone could help me, it would be great. This is my code so far:

```
$methods = array(
    'wedstrijden?club=Feyenoord'
);

$method = $methods[0];

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($url . $method));
print_rr($data);

function print_rr($data){

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($data);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
foreach($data as $row) {
    echo "home club is: " . $row->homeClub;
    echo "away club is: " . $row->awayClub;
}
```

you could also decode the json as associative array:

change `$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($url . $method));`

to `$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($url . $method), true);`

and iterate using:

```
<?php
foreach($data as $row) {
    echo "home club is: " . $row['homeClub'];
    echo "away club is: " . $row['awayClub'];
}
```

Oh, and **don't let SO'ers do your homework** :P